# Dynamic css values in zurb foundation

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass, zurb-foundation-5

I am building mobile web application through Zurb framework and Java.

In my application the css values are dynamic. The css values are configurable in the application properties. Now I am achieving through java.

Whether i can achieve this through Sass?

Comment: Do you want to use [varible](http://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-2) ?

Comment: @general03 yes, i want to use like variable,

Comment: So you have to write your own SCSS. In the SCSS file you put something like that `$primary-color: myValue` where `myValue` is your Java variable

Comment: @general03 Can we use Scss file in the java web application?

Comment: I think yes, you have to install `Grunt` for instance and command `grunt build` convert the SCSS to CSS

Comment: If it helps, a lazy workaround would be to inline the CSS and control it onpage, e.g. via PHP